# Need help- Selenium webdriver- click on element from visible list is not working

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, dropdownlistfor

I am sending defined data from excel file. I tried some code but they are not selecting all the data from excel file at some point of time code is giving me exception for WebElement not found.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div id="addDialog" class="hidden ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 30px; height: auto; max-height: 351.05px; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div class="field-container">
        <fieldset class="field-container">
            <legend>Contracts:</legend>
            <a class="select-all" href="#">Select All</a>
            <a class="deselect-all" href="#">Deselect All</a>
            <select id="addContract" class="searchable" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
                <option value="93370956">93370956</option>
                <option value="93796167">93796167</option>
                <option value="94203239">94203239</option>
            </select>
            <div id="ms-addContract" class="ms-container">
                <div class="ms-selectable">
                    <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="filter" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
                            <li id="86355560-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
                                <span>93370956</span>
                            </li>
                            <li id="202890296-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
                                <span>93796167</span>
                            </li>
                            <li id="938848030-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
                                <span>94203239</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Need to select values from list.
Efforts done:
This effort for code worked but it selected only one value and then gave exception

```
WebDriverWait Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
          Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span")));
          //now you can find element
          List<WebElement>options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"));
          for (WebElement option: options) {
            if(testData.equals(option.getText())) option.click();
          }
```

> Tried above code but it only selects one value !!

```
WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ms-addContract']//descendant::div[@class='ms-selectable']/ul[@class='ms-list']]//span")));  

List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ms-addContract']//descendant::div[@class='ms-selectable']/ul[@class='ms-list']]//span[contains(text(), '"+testData+"')]"));
            for (WebElement option : options) {
              if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
                option.click();--tried this xpath-no success

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(testData);
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.SPACE);
    //Clear the input text value.
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input")).clear();---worked but not satisfactory
```

Please need help to locate the element. I am using keyword driven framework reading values from excel file.

Comment: Which of the elements are failing? Currently it is quite hard to understand where your code is failing.

Comment: @MadisKangro it is not selecting the values from span class. when i run above tried code they just stuck on select all buttton.

Comment: add stacktrace =)

Comment: Remove additional `]` for this xpath `//ul[@class
='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'95757314')]]`

Comment: @Tuks . thanks for pointing out. But one issue is it selected only one first value from the list of values , it just skipped other value that was in the queue.

Comment: This is because you are matching only one value here  `List<WebElement>options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"));` so here it will find one element  because you are matching `span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]` So here `testData` will be single number  it will take only one value not all value.

Comment: @Tuks tried with this. driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']//li[@class='ms-elem-selectable']//span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]")); But no output

Comment: If you print the value of `testData` you will get the idea which you are passing for text match in xpath

Comment: i am printing around 10 values and all are matched from the list , but it only selected 3rd value...i dnt know why !!!!!!

Comment: @Payal Dhameliya, I think you have to put you option selection code in loop in the manner you printing the value

Comment: @Tuks not getting you

Comment: Can you update the question with your exact manual steps along with the URL if it is a public url? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get all span elements that are contained within a ul element (although correct me if I am wrong). This is the code you are using:

```
List<WebElement>options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"));
```

In your case, this XPath will only return 1 value. This is because you are trying to match the contents of each span with an input value "testData". If you want to get all span elements inside of the ul then use:

```
List<WebElement>options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span"));
```

This XPath will select accomplish selecting all span elements in the list. If you need to select only span elements containing text within your testData, then you can iterate over that list selecting the appropriate elements:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> optionsInTestData = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for(WebElement element: options){
    for(String data: testData){
        if(element.getText() == data){
            optionsInTestData.add(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type List<WebElement>  & Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable getting these errors for List and for (String data: testData). Tried to modified it . but still it is not working. There is List of testData so it should select them one by one .

Comment: I had same kind of situation , i used  List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-2']/li"));
   for (WebElement option : options) {
     if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
       option.click();
   } . it is working for that dropdown list.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I've programmed in Java. I've updated optionsInTestData to be an ArrayList instead of a List object. This should let you initialize it.

Comment: What object type is testData? If it is a List<String> you should be able to use the foreach loop. If its still giving you an error, you could always use the classic for(int i = 0; i < testData.size(); i++) {if testData.get(i) == element.getText()) { optionsInTestData.add(element);}}

Comment: Tried with code changes. still it is not going into the loop . testData is numbers string like u can see in html code

Comment: No, what data type is your testData object? String[], List<String>, int[], List<int>, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<int>, etc